# Iterating over a map, starting at a specific key

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, iterator, stdmap

I am implementing a function meant to find any strings that share a prefix with a given string.  All of the possible strings to compare to are in a map already, and I would like to iterate over that map starting at where the given string is. Currently, I am looping over the entire map, but for performance reasons, I need to make this more efficient.  This is how I am currently iterating over the map:

```
for(auto const& it : lookup_map){ //performs code }
```

I would like this to not start from the beginning of the map, but wherever the given string is in the map.

Answer (score 3):

Just use good old iterators:

```
for( auto it = lookup_map.find( your_string ); it != lookup_map.end(); ++it ) {
   // using it
}
```

Comment: This might need `lower_bound` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` has its own member function lower_bound for what you want to do. You can use [std::map::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/) to get your starting position and then do a compare of the prefix for subsequent iterations:

```
for (auto it = lookup_map.lower_bound(prefix);
    it != std::end(lookup_map) && it->first.compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix) == 0;
    ++it)
{
    ...
}
```

This will be more efficient than iterating every single key. The advantage in this case of using `lower_bound()` is that it will return the first item that is **equivalent or after** the search term. So if your search term is "aa" and you have an entry "aab" in your map, lower_bound() will return an iterator to "aab". I think this will be more useful in your case because you want to search on the prefix.

---

In C++20, `std::string` has a `starts_with()` function. So we can use this function to check the prefix and simplify our code a little:

```
for (auto it = lookup_map.lower_bound(prefix);
     it != lookup_map.end() && it->first.starts_with(prefix); ++it)
{
    ...
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fb3nGcj94)